# nginx redirect from www to no-www not working

Tags: node.js, nginx, server

I have a node.js app running on my AWS instance and I'm using NginX to serve it up.

I am trying to redirect the www.websitename.com traffic to websitename.com.  I have tried setting up a redirect in the etc/nginx/sites-available/websitename file and it looks like this:

```
upstream app_websitename {
    server 127.0.0.1:8000;
    keepalaive 8;
}
server {
    listen 0.0.0.0:80;
    server_name www.websitename.com;
    return 301 http://websitename.com$request_uri;
}
server {
    listen 0.0.0.0:80;
    server_name websitename.com;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/websitename.log;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

        proxy_pass http://app_websitename/;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
}
```

Any ideas are appreciated.  I have been trying stuff all over the place ;)

Answer (score 1):

replace this `listen 0.0.0.0:80;`  With

```
listen 80 ;
listen [::]:80;
```

Did you also add websitename.com to your host file ?

Comment: @wally thanks for your support. Its hard if your new to stackoverflow. I want to improve myself and help other ppl.

Answer (score 0):

It ended up being a problem with the way the company I bought the domain name from not saving my A-record properly. I spent a whole day wondering what I did wrong lol.